# XML, Python - save file structure

Tags: python, xml, filesystems, structured-data

I need to scan a large filesystem (1tb) and save this to an XML file. I want this XML file to be structured as described in the code.

Does anybody know how to read a directory and all its subdirectories and files one by one (so they can be added to an XML file) in Python?

```
<files>
    <file id = '1'>
        <name>myfile.file</name>
        <path>path/to/file/myfile.file</path>
    </file>
</files>
```

Comment: This answer is kind of in the question. Are you looking for a program to do this job?

Comment: @stmfunk that, or a way to read every file in a directory tree in Python. Will edit the Q

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to use a recursive procedure in conjunction with the `os` module. This module has functions for listing directory contents and telling if an item is a directory namely `os.listdir`, `os.path.isdir` and `os.path.isfile`. Using these you should be able to do what you are suggesting relatively easily. I do not know if you wish to preserve the directory structure or not, if not you can simply store the files and discard the directories.

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I was looking for. When I next have free time (its midnight and i probably wont be free until 6 PM tomorrow) ill try using that, and then accept it :)